# Why when I use java.util.Random in SpEL there is a SpelEvaluationException?

Tags: java, spring-el, spelevaluationexception

**beans.xml**

```
<bean id="duke" class="Juggler">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(java.util.Random).nextInt(10)}"/>
</bean>
```

Exceptions:

> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 20): Method call: Method nextInt(java.lang.Integer) cannot be found on java.util.Random type

Comment: `nextInt(int)` is not a static method.  You need an instance of `java.util.Random` in order to invoke `nextInt(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"value=#{ new java.util.Random().ints(1, 0, 10).sum() }"
```

[SpEL doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based)

Answer (score -2):

Probably such way you can call only static methods